# Animação ao modificar altura do LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou modificando a altura de um *`LinearLayout`* de *`WRAP_CONTENT`* 
para *`0`* (zero) e vice-versa ouvindo o evento *`onClick`* de um *`Button`*.

Gostaria que essa mudança ocorra gradualmente durante alguns milissegundos, como *`700ms`*, por exemplo. Como faço isso usando a menor quantidade de código possível?

Trecho do código:

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.teste);
ll.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 0;
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

Isso muda a altura para zero, porém sem transição.

**EDITADO**:
O efeito é parecido com esse [link](https://jsbin.com/hucerarera/edit?output) porém na vertical

Comment: Eu recomendaria usar `ObjectAnimator` ou `ViewPropertyAnimator`, ou até mesmo o atributo `animateLayoutChanges`, nada de `Threads` :P Mas realmente, se o código relevante onde está fazendo essa modificação fica complicado ajudar.

Comment: É porque só estou mudando a altura do LinearLayout, então não adicionei código... Vou adicionar

Comment: Blz, vou dar uma sugestão assim que colocar o código.

Comment: No código estou testando com Click no próprio elemento, depois só irei mudar esse Click para um botão, mas com o efeito no LinearLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta tem quatro etapas:

1. Obter o tamanho final do seu container;
2. Obter o tamanho inicial;
3. Criar um `ValueAnimator` para variar do tamanho inicial ao tamanho final em 700ms;
4. Setar o valor da altura e redimensionar o container a cada iteração do `ValueAnimator`.

---

```
Button button = ...; //Seu button
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.teste);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = ll.getLayoutParams();

        int finalHeight = 0;
        int initialHeight = ll.getHeight();

        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(initialHeight, finalHeight);

        va.setDuration(700);
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                params.height = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                ll.requestLayout();
            }
        });

        va.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Unnecessary unboxing "value.intValue()". Também não está mudando a altura do elemento.

Comment: De fato, já percebi o problema do seu código, vou ajustar. Você estava setando o clickListener no LinearLayout, não no botão.

Comment: Legal a abordagem Wakim. +1

Comment: Adicionei 2 Logs, um para o ClickListener e outro para o UpdateListener. Somente o click é detectado. Como disparo o UpdateListener?

Comment: Bem lembrado, faltou iniciar a animação, erro meu.

Comment: Mudei a duração para 2000, após pressionar o botão ele está levando 2000ms para reduzir o tamanho do LinearLayout, e quando diminui é de uma só vez, sem efeito de transição. O Log do UpdateListener está aparecendo várias vezes, acredito que seja o progresso de redução do elemento, mas em UI não está funcionando

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta pois está ambígua.

Comment: @JhonatanPereira, pelo que entendi, ele está funcionando ao incrementar a altura mas não funciona ao decrementar? Ou nem isso? Fiquei com essa dúvida.

Comment: @Wakim's ele decrementa a altura, mas não por estágios. Ou seja, ele vai de X pixels até zero direto, sem efeito. Deixei um exemplo na pergunta, feito com HTML e CSS.

Comment: Esses milissegundos está somente atrasando (delay) a mudança de altura

Comment: Ah blz, vou fazer um teste aqui em um device. Acredito que se a variação for de 0 até o valor desejado ele funcione, já o contrário, do valor desejado até 0 fique estranho (nesse caso é só fazer o inverso).

Comment: @JhonatanPereira, ajustei o ponto onde recupera a altura. Se você usar `wrap_content`, o `LayoutParams.height` vai retornar `-2`. Nesse caso você precisar usar o `View.getHeight`.

Comment: Funcionou! Valeu, man :D

Answer (score 1):

Bem, como você foi especifico na quantidade de codigo, o melhor resultado seria esse:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.teste);
ll.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = 0;
        ll.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    v.setLayoutParams(params);
                }, 700);
        ll.getLayoutParams().height = originaltamanhodoseulayout
    }
});
```

voce precisa saber a altura original do seu "ll" para voltar ele para a alttura original depois.
Explicando:
ele roda em background por 700ms deixando o "ll" com height = 0 e quando terminar reverte ele para a altura original.

Acredito que com menor linhas de codigo seria esse, eu já uso isso aqui com resultado positivo, embora para outras finalidades.

da uma conferida ae

Comment: Vou testar daqui a pouco. Vou editar a pergunta, pois está ambígua, dá uma olhada para ver se é compatível com sua resposta.